# When is specifying parameter types in lambda expressions necessary

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Currently, I see no difference in the following **Java 8** lambda expressions:

Parameter types **specified**:

```
Arrays.sort(strArray, (String s1, String s2) -> s2.length() - s1.length());
```

Parameter types **omitted**:

```
Arrays.sort(strArray, (s1, s2) -> s2.length() - s1.length());
```

**EDIT: In general, what are the *pros* and *cons* for specifying parameter types in Java 8 lambda expressions? And when is it necessary to specify?**

I've thought of few possible reasons (but I'm sure there are more):

- additional type safety checks when specified
- better code readability

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference.  It's up to you what the tradeoff is.  But frankly, you're better off writing neither of these; instead, `import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt` and do `Arrays.sort(strArray, comparingInt(String::length))`.  The first version isn't exactly more type-safe; the second version will infer exactly the same type information and enforce it exactly as much.

Comment: What about for more general cases of lambda expressions? Such as those for `map()` and `reduce()` as well as other functional programming methods. Not just for comparators.

Comment: Java can't always infer the parameter type.  (If you got that impression from @chengpohi, it's wrong.)  So sometimes you do _have_ to specify the parameter type.  But if you don't have to, it's up to you whether or not to leave it in; there's no real difference.

Comment: When is it absolutely _necessary_ to specify the parameter type? Can you give an example? I'm new to Java 8

Comment: `Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.length()).reversed());` won't compile.  `Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt((String s) -> s.length()).reversed());` will.

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning why the call to `reversed` needs to be included in this example. `Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.length()))` compiles. The difference is that in that case the invocation of `comparingInt` is a poly expression in a method invocation context, and in that context the string type of `s` can be inferred from the type of array; whereas in the call to `reversed`, the type of `s` is inferred separately and is resolved to `Object` without looking at the type of `array`.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda function element type is decided by the operate element type.(`strArray`):

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) {
}
```

the comparator type is `generics` and it's decided by your passed parameter type.

The other `lambda` function is also same:

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);
T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator);
...
```

so specify parameter type or not, the compiler already has known what's the parameter type should be.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of what @louis-wasserman said in the comments, there is another good example of an instance where you might want to ask that question:

```
// DOES NOT compile
Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInts(str -> str.length()).reversed());

// DOES compile
Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInts((String str) -> str.length()).reversed());
```

The way I understand it, `Comparator.reversed()` requires some sort of contract as to how the collection is inherently ordered. Without knowing the type of `str` it will not know the return type of `.length()`, thus violating this contract.

Comment: See my comment under Louis Wasserman's comment.